# Fortran Error # 6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform in one-dimensional array multiplication

Tags: fortran

This is just a simple program written in Visual Studio Community 2022, the array dN has the size of 1×8 and array ddN has the size of 8×1 (transpose of dN), but when I execute the code "place1==matmul(ddN,dN)", it reminds

```
Compiling with Intel® Fortran Compiler 2024.0.0 [Intel(R) 64]...
Console1.f90
G:\FHL\Interface\abaqus\multifield\abaqus_cae\Fortran Test\Console1\Console1.f90(42): error #6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform.   [PLACE1]
compilation aborted for G:\FHL\Interface\abaqus\multifield\abaqus_cae\Fortran Test\Console1\Console1.f90 (code 1)

Build log written to  "file://G:/FHL/Interface/abaqus/multifield/abaqus_cae/Fortran%20Test/Console1/x64/Debug/BuildLog.htm"
Console1 - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

the size of dN and ddN is matched, so I don't konw why this problem appears.

If anyone could provide some help to solve this problem, I will be very grateful.

This is the program:

```
program Console1

implicit none

! Variables
real, dimension(1,8) :: dN
real, dimension(8,1) :: ddN
real, dimension(1,1) :: dddN
real, dimension(1,1) :: place1
integer :: r
integer :: s
integer :: t

! Body of Console1
r=1.d0
s=-1.d0
t=1.d0
    dN(1,1) = 0.125d0*(1.d0-r)*(1.d0-s)*(1.d0+t)
    dN(1,2) = 0.125d0*(1.d0+r)*(1.d0-s)*(1.d0+t)
    dN(1,3) = 0.125d0*(1.d0+r)*(1.d0+s)*(1.d0+t)
    dN(1,4) = 0.125d0*(1.d0-r)*(1.d0+s)*(1.d0+t)
    dN(1,5) = 0.125d0*(1.d0-r)*(1.d0-s)*(1.d0-t)
    dN(1,6) = 0.125d0*(1.d0+r)*(1.d0-s)*(1.d0-t)
    dN(1,7) = 0.125d0*(1.d0+r)*(1.d0+s)*(1.d0-t)
    dN(1,8) = 0.125d0*(1.d0-r)*(1.d0+s)*(1.d0-t)  
    
    ddN=transpose(dN)
    place1=matmul(ddN,dN)
    print *, dN
    print *, ddN
    print *, size(dN,1)
    print *, size(dN,2)
    print *, size(ddN,1)
    print *, size(ddN,2)
    print *, place1
    pause
end program Console1
```

I'm just a begineer of Fortran and I'm not major in programming, so my question may be a bit navie. I will still be very grateful if anyone could offer timely help.

Comment: You are multiplying an 8 x 1 matrix by a 1 x 8. That is OK, but the result would be an 8 x 8 matrix, not the 1 x 1 matrix that you are trying to put it in. I won't hazard a formal answer, because I'm not sure whether you want an inner product of what are essentially vectors or an outer one. However, dot_product might be what you actually need for an inner product.

Answer (score 0):

As can be read in [the documentation for `matmul`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MATMUL.html) (GFortran documentation, not the iFort, but the function should behave the same):

> The rank shall be one or two, and the first (or only) dimension of MATRIX_B shall be equal to the last (or only) dimension of MATRIX_A. MATRIX_A and MATRIX_B shall not both be rank one arrays.
> Return value:

The two arguments of `matmul` don't match up in your case with their dimensions.

Perhaps you intend to use the reverse:

```
    place1=matmul(dN,ddN)
```

Then the corresponding dimensions align properly.